# Why is the following code not compilable?

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

The code below should replace particular elements of some table `acccolumns` if some condition is satisfied:

```
comp1 = Compile[{{acccolumns, _Real, 2}}, Module[{acccols, ncols, acc},
   ncols = Length[acccolumns[[1]]];
   acccols = acccolumns;
   acc = 0;
   Do[Do[
     acc = RandomInteger[{0, 1}];
     If[acc == 0, acccols[[j]][[i]] = RandomReal[{0, 1}]], {i, 1, 
      ncols, 1}], {j, 1, Length[acccols], 1}];
   acccols], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

It is not compilable:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@comp1

        1 argument
        1 Boolean register
        10 Integer registers
        3 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking off
        RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}

        T(R2)0 = A1
        I2 = 0
        I0 = 1
        Result = T(R2)2

1   T(R1)2 = Part[ T(R2)0, I0]
2   I1 = Length[ T(R1)2]
3   T(R2)2 = CopyTensor[ T(R2)0]]
4   I3 = I2
5   I5 = Length[ T(R2)2]
6   I6 = I2
7   goto 18
8   I7 = I1
9   I8 = I2
10  goto 17
11  I9 = RandomInteger[ I2, I0]]
12  I3 = I9
13  B0 = I3 == I2
14  if[ !B0] goto 17
15  V17I8T(R2)2I6 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{acccolumns, iCompile$1, \
acccolsCompile$2, jCompile$3}, Block[{i = iCompile$1, acccols = \
acccolsCompile$2, j = jCompile$3}, {acccols[[j]][[i]] = \
RandomReal[{0, 1}], i, acccols, j}]][ T(R2)0, I8, T(R2)2, I6]]
16  goto 17
17  if[ ++ I8 <= I7] goto 11
18  if[ ++ I6 <= I5] goto 8
19  Return
```

Could you please tell me what the problem is with the string `acccols[[j]][[i]] = RandomReal[{0, 1}]`?

Comment: No need for double `Part`. Try `acccols[[j, i]] = ...`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit : thanks! Do you know how to speedup this equation? I tried with `Compile`GetElement[acccols, j,i] = RandomReal[{0,1}];` but it becomes not compilable.

Comment: Just replace `acccols[[j]][[i]]` with `acccols[[j, i]]` in your code and it should compile fully.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit : yes, you are correct. But it is potentially slow if compared with using `Compile`GetElement[acccols,j,i]` instead of `acccols[[j, i]]`.

Comment: My guess is that it is potentially slower, but hard to say without testing. Also it is faster to do this at the row rather than element level. Can be done like so. `comp3 = Compile[{{acccolumns, _Real, 2}},
   Module[{acccols = acccolumns, ncols = Length[acccolumns[[1]]], 
     mask},
    Do[
     mask = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, ncols];
     acccols[[j]] = 
      mask*RandomReal[{0, 1}, ncols] + (1 - mask)*acccols[[j]]
     , {j, Length[acccols]}];
    acccols]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];`

Comment: (1) `GetElement` must be a read, not a write, operation. (2) Why not this?: `comp2 = Compile[{{acccolumns, _Real, 2}}, Map[If[RandomInteger[{0, 1}] == 0, RandomReal[{0, 1}], #] &, acccolumns, {2}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]`. [Can be combined with Daniel's idea and map over level `1`.]

Comment: I think the problem is probably a parsing restriction (or bug): `Set[Part[x,...], val]` is parsed as compilable (Sjoerd's fix), but a nested `Part` such as `Set[Part[Part[acccols, j], i], val]` is not. And `acccols[[j]][[i]]` is syntactically a nested `Part`; try `acccols[[j]][[i]] // Hold // FullForm`.

Comment: For instance, `Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, x[[2]][[1]]] // CompilePrint` and `Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, x[[2, 1]]] // CompilePrint` produce different codes that run with different speeds. So it's more like a parsing restriction.